# Is it possible to get the most popular artist per city with the Spotify API?

Tags: spotify, spotify-app, spotify-queue

I am wondering if it is possible to get the most popular artist of my city with the Spotify API.

Answer (score 1):

The current API (2016-05) doesn't seem to provide location specific queries. Artists of a city would be found in the [Search for an Item](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/)-API-reference but there's no such a dedicated possibility.

You could search for keywords mentioning your city or for tags including your city (`tag:Berlin`) but you'd certainly not obtain all artists of that city with this type of query.

But say you had all artists of a particular city, you'd still have to measure how successful these artists actually are.
A rather easy metric would be to collect [an artist's top tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artists-top-tracks/) and evaluate the `popularity` integer value of these tracks. These values can be compared to other artists (e.g. for a first trial by average popularity).